# Same Name, Lame!

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Write a function or program that, when given a list of names, outputs or returns a list where duplicates of given names have a unique shortened version of their surname.

#### Input:

A list of names, where a name is defined by a given name and a last name separated by a space. Names are non-empty strings containing only uppercase and lowercase letters. The list can be an array of strings, or the names separated by a constant non-alpha, non-space character, but the output must be in the same format as the input.

#### Output:

A list of the inputted names in the same order and format as the input that have been modified by these rules:

- For unique given names, output just the given name
- For names that share the same given name:

  - As well as their given name, add the shortest unique version of their surname that that is not shared by another name, followed by a period. For instance:
    `John Clancy, John Smith` becomes `John C.,John S.` and `James Brown, James Bratte` becomes `James Bro.,James Bra.`
  - If one surname is a subset of another, such as `Julian King,Julian Kingsley`, return the full surname of the smaller one without a period. The example would become `Julian King,Julian King.`
- Basically a period represents the regex `.+`, where *only* one name should match it.
- You may assume that no-one will share both the same given name and the same surname
- Names are case-sensitive

#### Test Cases:

- `John Clancy,Julie Walker,John Walker,Julie Clancy` -> `John C.,Julie W.,John W.,Julie C.`
- `Julian King,Jack Johnson,Julian Kingsley` > `Julian King,Jack,Julian King.`
- `Jack Brown,Jack Black,Jack Blue` > `Jack Br.,Jack Bla.,Jack Blu.`
- `John Storm,Jon Snow,Johnny Storm` > `John,Jon,Johnny`
- `Jill DeSoma,Jill Desmond` > `Jill DeS.,Jill Des.`
- `XxXnO sCOppeXxX,XxXNO MERCYXxX` > `XxXnO,XxXNO`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest byte count for each language wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118596/uniquify-identifiers), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/golf-down-the-ppcg-usernames) (Thanks @Laikoni). [Sandbox Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14498/76162)

Comment: Where does the `Angela C.` come from the in the test case?

Comment: Meant to be a `Julie` oops, thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>34 33 32</s>  30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;\ċÐf⁶t€⁶;€JṖḊ$$¦”.µ€ċ@ÐṂ€Ẏ$Ḣ€
```

A monadic link taking a list of lists of characters (i.e. a list of "strings") and returning the abbreviations in the same format and relative order.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9865kj34Qlpjxq3lTxqWgOkrIGU18Od0x7u6FJRObTsUcNcvUNbgWJHuh0OT3i4swnIfLirT@XhjkVA1v@HOxcDVegcbs8CUVwPd285uudwO1BGJQtkXMMcBV07BaBU5P//XvkZeQrOOYl5yZU6XqU5makK4Yk52alFOmAJGBssAVHFBeIk5il4Z@al63glJmcrgFQW5@fpIEkU56QCFYIknYryy/Mg6pxygCSMWZrKBbYhuCS/KBdoGZCVl18OtjWvEiLK5ZWZk6Pgkhqcn5uoA2UX5@bnpXBFVETk@SsUO/sXFKQC2TpA7Oev4Osa5BwJZAIA)** (a full program test suite)

#### How?

```
;\ċÐf⁶t€⁶;€JṖḊ$$¦”.µ€ċ@ÐṂ€Ẏ$Ḣ€ - Link: list of lists    e.g. ["Sam Ng","Sam Li","Sue Ng"]
                   µ€          - monadically for €ach:  e.g. "Sue Ng"
 \                             -   cumulative reduce with:
;                              -     concatenation           ["S","Su","Sue","Sue ","Sue N","Sue Ng"]
     ⁶                         -   literal space character   ' '
   Ðf                          -   filter keep if:
  ċ                            -     count (spaces)          ["Sue ","Sue N","Sue Ng"]
        ⁶                      -   literal space character   ' '
      t€                       -   trim from €ach            ["Sue","Sue N","Sue Ng"]
                 ”.            -   literal period character  '.'
                ¦              -   sparse application...
         ;€                    -   ...of: concatenate €ach (with a period)
                               -   ...only for these indexes:
               $               -     last two links as a monad:
           J                   -       range of length       [1,2,3]
              $                -       last two links as a monad:
            Ṗ                  -         pop                 [1,2]
             Ḋ                 -         dequeue             [2]  (i.e. 2,3,...,length-1)
                               -   ...i.e.:                  ["Sue","Sue N.","Sue Ng"]
                               -                   yielding: [["Sam","Sam N.","Sam Ng"],["Sam","Sam L.","Sam Li"],["Sue","Sue N.","Sue Ng"]]
                           $   - last two links as a monad:
                          Ẏ    -   tighten                   ["Sam","Sam N.","Sam Ng","Sam","Sam L.","Sam Li","Sue","Sue N.","Sue Ng"]
                       ÐṂ€     -   filter keep minimals for €ach: 
                     ċ@        -     count (sw@ping args)    [["Sam N.","Sam Ng"],["Sam L.","Sam Li"],["Sue","Sue N.","Sue Ng"]]
                            Ḣ€ - head €ach                   ["Sam N.","Sam L.","Sue"]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 130 bytes

```python
def f(a):n=[[x[:i]+'.'*(' 'in x[:i]<x)for i in range(x.find(' '),len(x)+1)]for x in a];print[min(x,key=sum(n,[]).count)for x in n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xboMwEIb3PIXFgp0g1HbokDZLaJdULVIzNJVlVRaYxMKckQEFnp76EClDl9N/930n/fXQXiw8jGOuClJQybaw47znWy02YRyuaUhCDWQ6PPessI5o4g9OwlnRPi405OiwyCigPdvcM4FSj5IUT7XT0PJKexaVatg1XUUh4oLFme2gZX8uiBHzD2Z@J9aPW19HQ921lLExONgLkMRIyIYgCg6d0Yp8SVMqhyvCZZvg4mpjyItqKgt5sJqoBPKm4YxQZiXB98bC/DrDxqgBdRT2zl7hZu@Nn8vSKbSwwLG1rpra@Az2OheDYSarW5WjreT/Yqf@BClpkrSulc9e8PMjJe@vn8k3Hn4B)

First generates all the nicknames, as follows:

```python
n == [
    ['John', 'John .', 'John C.', 'John Cl.', 'John Cla.', 'John Clan.', 'John Clanc.', 'John Clancy'],
    ['Julie', 'Julie .', 'Julie W.', 'Julie Wa.', 'Julie Wal.', 'Julie Walk.', 'Julie Walke.', 'Julie Walker'],
    ['John', 'John .', 'John W.', 'John Wa.', 'John Wal.', 'John Walk.', 'John Walke.', 'John Walker'],
    ['Julie', 'Julie .', 'Julie C.', 'Julie Cl.', 'Julie Cla.', 'Julie Clan.', 'Julie Clanc.', 'Julie Clancy'],
    ['Jill', 'Jill .', 'Jill D.', 'Jill De.', 'Jill Des.', 'Jill Desm.', 'Jill Desmo.', 'Jill Desmon.', 'Jill Desmond']
]
```

Then picks the first* one from each list that is *least frequent* in `sum(n,[])`. This will always be the first unique nickname.

Note that `n` includes the erroneous nicknames `'John .'` etc., but they will never be picked.

(*CPython 2.7’s `min` does so, anyway. This code [may not be portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6783101/257418)!)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) <s>165 162 161</s> 160 bytes

Includes 1 trailing space if only the given name is returned, eg. `"John "`

```
->a,n=0,s=0{a.group_by{|i|i[n]}.values.flat_map{|i|j=i[0];k=j.index' ';i.size<2?j.size>n ?j[0,[n+1,k].max-(s>1?0:1)]+(n>k ??.:''):j:f[i,n+=1,i.count{|l|l[n]}]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Rb4IwFIXf9yv6Vo21gT3igES3F5fNZD7MhTWmanGFckuoTJn42xl1LPhyc84932lvUW6qJvY/m3HACfgOMb5z5nRf6DJfb6pzLWsZAbvQb65KYWis@GGd8dwGiS8jh01SP6ESduKEEZ5IauSPeLgPk6sIAIVJ5JAIRi5JGc34aTwwgRs6njtkowEEKQpD6mE89BIvjiSBke8SSbe6hMO5VrWyv7PLpclRHEV4rr8AzRSHbYUJnpdKCvTOVSoKa23Yu2vYsYzddQ@0Ww7oWcLeMnybIlszGrpKFxolbluWmxb6CP@lqWpnb0pxA9szlgddZNebWg362J0HVZf0tFQKPYqlzrhl/pzJNOx6ZnVawQKZ2SLPRatbrp2vC/Ty9Db7sAvGml8)

163 bytes if you don't want the trailing space

```
->a,n=0,s=0{a.group_by{|i|i[n]}.values.flat_map{|i|j=i[0];k=j.index' ';i.size<2?j.size>n ?j[0..[n,k-1].max-(s>1?0:1)]+(n>k ??.: ''):j:f[i,n+1,i.count{|l|l[n+1]}]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Bb4JAEIXv/RV7QyNsoEcskGh7sWlN6qE2241ZdbELyyxhpUqF305ZS4OXybz3vjeZotxWbRx8tk7IbAhcWwfuheFDocp8s60utagFAdrgbyZLrnEs2XGTsdwESSCIS6dpkGABe362kDUVWIsf/nAfJdclBBQlxMWYgJ06HsUZOzsjHXqR63tjOhlBmKIowj6yrLGf@DERNkw8W@CdKuF4qWUtSWfQhjZNm6OYEGuhvgDNJYNdZdnWopSCo3cmU14YacJBXcOepfSuP9C5DNCzgINh2C5FpqYV9JU@1JLftgw3K9QJ/ksz2c1BlPwGNm@sjqrIrj91O6hT/x5UfTLQQkr0yFcqY4b5UzpTsB@Y9XkNS6Tnyzzn3d5x3Xxdopent/mHMShtfwE)